# Minecraft server lagging with enough RAM

Tags: server, java, minecraft

I have recently installed a Minecraft server on my Debian 11 VPS with `Java 19.0.1` and my Minecraft server jar is a `spigot 1.19.2`.

I have installed Minecraft servers in the past and I never had issues with lags or something. Now my Debian 11 VPS has 16GB of RAM and 6 Cores (although Minecraft runs on 1 core primarily as far as I know) and we have just started playing on it so nothing crazy going on on there and it still lags pretty frequently.

I'm starting my server in a screen with `screen ./start.sh` which has the following in it:
`java -Xms2G -Xmx13G -jar server.jar nogui` So the server itself keeps 3GB of RAM to operate which for a Debian should be way more than enough.

My Server is hosted by a hosting service in Germany and I am situated in Switzerland. Latency is good and the distance is not far. My internet speed is good as well and all of the players (around 3-4 most of the time) are having this lag issues as well.

Any ideas? Tips?

Comment: what kind of lag? chunk loading issues? things not updating right away? something else? Also, just noticed this is a question about Debian, which is off-topic here on Ask Ubuntu. This site is only for questions about supported flavors of Ubuntu. You can try [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) where it would be on-topic, or possibly ask at [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Only Ubuntu versions are supported here - maybe try the Debian forums.